# Sync tabs with tableview scroll in IOS

Tags: ios, tabs, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol, swift5

I am working on a food delivery app where in a single store i have multiple menu categories. I have items in single tableview. So when i reach the header ( for example Breakfast then Breakfast tab should be active ) of each section how to change tab accordingly?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqhMq.gif)

Answer (score 0):

use this two method to put header in section..

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section \(section)"
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let vw = UIView()
    vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return vw
}
```